# Violation of PH assumption Cox model

Tags: survival, cox-model, proportional-hazards

So, i have seen similar questions to mine here but still can´t quite understand why this is happening.
I´ve ajusted a cox model and now i´m testing the PH assumption. This are my results:[image]

It is probably usefull to say that my data has 14972 individuals.
The Schoenfeld plots are the following:
[image]
I´ve read in another question that this results may have to do with the size of the sample. I would like to be sure that this variables are indeed non-time dependent. I´ve tried to use rms library to do the log-minus-log graph and ended up with this error: Error in UseMethod("survplot") :
no applicable method for 'survplot' applied to an object of class "survfit"
Anyone can help? Thank you so much!

Comment: The Schoenfeld residual plots are better than log-log plots in most cases.  For particular `rms` questions post a reply at `datamethods.org/rms`.    Make sure all your predictor are time zero (or earlier) predictors.  Show an enlarged single graph for the residual plot with the smallest p-value and make its trend line visable (thick black line etc.).

Comment: It looks like you are creating the residual plots using the survminer::ggcoxzph function? If so, it can be helpful to highlight the residual plots for the most problematic variables. Also, as Frank suggests, some of the default variable values that ggcoxzph uses don't work well for all scenarios: increase the transparency of the red dots and reduce the y-axis limits. For example, for the Regiao variable, try ggcoxzph(res.zph1, point.alpha = 0.05, var = "Regiao", ylim = c(-15, 15)). The purpose here is to try to see the actual shape and extent of the potential non-linearity.